# Create 'WebService' so will work in a console application

Tags: c#, web-services

I know you can do it easily with [WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013896/is-it-possible-to-create-a-standalone-c-sharp-web-service-deployed-as-an-exe-or) - But I need for our system to use the old way using the 'System.Web.Services.WebService'

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the problem in this question? I goggled a long time with no results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer - Its found there because this its more common to do it in a winodws service

http://jakkaj.wordpress.com/2007/10/25/web-service-inside-a-windows-service-without-iis/