# Can you add a web service to an existing Windows Service project (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-services

I already have a Windows Service project that runs scheduled tasks as part of a larger application.  I want to add some Web Services to it (i.e. SOAP), so that some .NET clients can connect and request services (this is all on a LAN, not over the internet).  The server application is a Service Project with references to some class library projects.

Is this something that can be done, or does the web service require that I create an ASP.NET project?  Sorry for the very basic question, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. No need for ASP.Net. See for ex. *ServiceHost* or *WebServiceHost* of WCF

Comment: After posting the question, SO then suggested [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013896/is-it-possible-to-create-a-standalone-c-sharp-web-service-deployed-as-an-exe-or?rq=1) which may, in fact, answer my question.  I will have to spend some time reading the links over there first before I'm sure.  It was not my intention to create a duplicate.

Comment: And another example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899360/getting-a-post-endpoint-to-work-in-self-hosted-webservicehost-c-sharp-webservi

Comment: See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api (for Web API, I'd go with it)

Comment: and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (for WCF)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new WCF service without creating an APS.NET webservice and you can use SOAP to communicate with it.

Maybe this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that a Windows Service can "self host" WCF WebServices using the `ServiceHost` class.

Relevant article: [Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Specific section: [Hosting in Windows Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#msdnwcfhc_topic4).